# mysql stored procedure parameters don't seem to work with "@" (At sign)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I'm changing a MS SQL database over to MySQL.

I've rewritten one of the stored procedures which takes a parameter called `@Account_Number`.  When I run the stored procedure in MySQL I get the following Message:  `Error Code: 1048 Column 'Account_Number' cannot be null`.

Using the workbench I finally tinkered around and figured out that when I removed the "@" from my stored procedures and renamed them like `parmAccount_Number` the stored procedure would execute.

I really want to keep the stored procedure input parameters named the same, and I don't want to go back and rename my MS SQL parameters... just in case I want to flip flop Databases.

I can't find any info on what MySQL does with the "@"....

Is there a way to make it work with "@"  ?

**EDIT**

Declaring the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `My_sp`(
 `@Account_Number` varchar(8),....)
```

insert portion of sp

```
insert into 
My_Table
(
    Account_Number, ...
)
values
(
    @Account_Number,...
)
```

Comment: Any chance of posting a little code, perhaps a before and after so we can see what you've got?

Comment: Hope that helps... cut out other fields so the edit would not be so huge...

Comment: Thanks for that - I believe @spencer7593 has provided an appropriate answer to the question (+1).

Comment: @pStan: Interesting. I've never tried enclosing procedure variables or parameter names in backticks, like you have shown above. (I've only ever used the backticks for identifiers in SQL statements (table names, column names.)  Given that you're able to get the procedure compiled, you might try enclosing the parameter reference in backticks as well. Presumably, MySQL won't see that as user defined variable, and might actually see it as a reference to the parameter name. (I've not tested that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't name MySQL procedure variables starting with the `@` sign.

The `@` sign character signifies a MySQL User-Defined Variable, which is quite different than a procedure variable.

The big differences is that user defined variable aren't declared (they don't have a datatype), and they have scope within a session (database connection), not just a procedure. It persists for the entire session. (This also means it's subject to modification anywhere in the session, any SQL statement, trigger, function or procedure can modify it, which makes it very useful, and also makes it a potential pitfall.

It's possible to use user defined variables as the actual values passed to a procedure or function. But you can't name MySQL procedure variables or parameters starting with an `@` sign.

I believe this is compliant with the SQL 2003 standards.

Documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

**UPDATE**

Interesting.

Given that you are able to get a procedure compiled by enclosing the parameter name in backticks (as shown in the example statement you added)...

You might try enclosing the parameter name reference in the INSERT statement in backticks as well. (I've never tested that; I've never tried "back ticking" variable names before; I've never seen that done before.)  But if the procedure is actually compiling, then maybe that would work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  That is a bit of a bummer though.  Perhaps I can add a wrapper into my DAL to change my "@" to a "p_" if the  DB type is mysql vs msSQL.  That way I can leave most of my code alone, and not change my msSQL stored stored procedures either.